# Chaining function calls in main. Is it "Pythonic"?

Tags: python

Lately, some of my code has led me to a question about using outputs of functions as variables, then to use those same variables as parameters in other functions.  All when defining main.  I believe this can lead to errors when debugging and confusion when using a file as a module.

An example is below:

```
def add_two_numbers(x, y):
    z = x + y
    return z

def now_divide_two(z, s):
    t = z / s 
    return t
```

**First method:**

```
def main():
    added = add_two_numbers(5, 10)
    final_output = now_divide_two(added, 3)
    print(final_output)
```

**Second method:**

```
def main():
    final_output = now_divide_two(add_two_numbers(5,10), 3)
    print(final_output)
```

Style guides and good practice suggest the first method is superior to the second.  Yet, I still feel that they are both "unpythonic".  With that, let's assume functions become more complicated, but still require the principle of using each others outputs as the next one's parameters.  What is the recommended methodology for running functions in main?

Comment: Which style guide?

Comment: "All when defining main" Note, "main" doesn't have any special status in Python.

Comment: What this has to do with `main()` anyway?  Usually `main` is just for parsing command line arguments and setting up logging.  First way is preferable regardless, just clearer to read and easier to step through in debuggers.

Comment: Which do you like better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing unpythonic about passing the results of a function to another function. It's often the best way of doing things.

The first style is better than the second style in terms of clarity because it's a lot easier to tell what the value being passed to `now_divide_two` represents. In the second method, you aren't declaring the variable to be passed to `now_divide_two`, so you have to guess what the value you're passing represents. In the first method, there is a variable with a name, so you know reasonably well what the variable means and why you are passing it to another function.

Sometimes, however, it's easy to assume what the arguments to functions mean (like `str` for example), and in those cases it can be better to just pass the results of the function directly to the other function.

Comment: I would add that one way to get "the best of both worlds" is to use named function arguments when calling a function with a complex expression as an argument. This "simulates" using a local variable name, without actually using a local variable name.

Answer (score -1):

Functionally, both approaches are equivalent (barring minor differences such as temporary vs explicitly named variables), so neither is inherently "better" than the other.

"Better" is a matter of practical needs and circumstances. Some concrete considerations to help you decide in the cases you may encounter:

- The one line approach uses fewer lines of code. This is sometimes (very seldom) important.
- Using a temporary variable instead of a new namespace entry *may*, in some cases provide a *very marginal* performance boost. This is again neither a likely nor worthwhile optimization to pursue in most situations.
- If you want to log or otherwise process the intermediate values, you will have to use the multiline approach.
- Having more shorter lines is generally more readable. Readability is more useful than brevity, especially with a language like Python.

As you can tell, I personally tend to lean towards having intermediate assignments rather than monolithic one liners. However, that's usually a matter of taste. When possible, weigh the pros and cons of different approaches. Sometimes you have to recognize that it really doesn't matter, and just go with what seems nicer to you in the moment.

Answer (score -2):

First method is imperative. Second is functional. Many people outside of academic contexts tend to use imperative style, citing readability as the reason. If you prefer the second style you may like Lisp or Clojure, where functional programming is dominant

Comment: This isn't true at all. Why would the first be "imperative" and the second "functional"?

Comment: in the first, you're creating mutable state variable "added". if you extend the nesting approach you will not produce any mutable state

Comment: You aren't avoiding "creating mutable state". That's almost impossible to avoid in Python. Python can never hope to be purely functional, but if you call one "functional", the other one doesn't actually mutate any state, so it is still "functional", and they are both equally so. I mean, you also create "mutable state" when you assign to `final_output`... And anyway, what are you going to do? Use entirely anonymous functions, the whole way down, to avoid creating "mutable state" of the variables that reference your functions?

Comment: yes, i agree assigning to `final_output` is also creating mutable state. however, i think what OP is asking is the nesting (chaining) where return value is not mutated. You can check Clojure for examples of purely functional code

Comment: They never mention mutation at all, and the intermediate variable is never mutated. Yes, I am aware of purely functional programming languages with immutable variables.

Comment: I don't think this answer deserves downvotes like this. As a matter of fact, there is a certain "style" that is well-loved in some functional language communities (I'm looking at you, Haskell) which goes out of its way to use only function composition and not named values. You may argue that that's not very Pythonic, but I think it certainly can be very functional.

Comment: @DanielPryden yes, but in Haskell, if you write in a style that eschews named values, that doesn't make your code *more functional*, and it certainly doesn't make it *imperative* if you do use a lot of named values. But I agree, in those communities there is a love for terseness and a hate of verbosity. `xs` and `ys` and all that

Comment: if you don't create named values, you can't accidentally mutate them

Comment: In that sense, function composition serves a purpose beyond "eschewing named values." I don't know if the goal is "love of terseness" or "hate of verbosity" so much as it is helping to enforce immutability and the functional paradigm...

Comment: Not in Haskell, dude, that is enforced by the language. You *can't* mutate a variable.